# Why can't exhaustive search parsing stop after |w| + 1 derivations?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers

If my grammar does not have productions of the form $A\rightarrow\lambda$ and $A\rightarrow B$ for some variables $A$ and $B$ then I know that each step in the derivation must involve an increase in the sentential length. Therefore if I do an exhaustive search for some word $w$ then I know I can stop searching after $|w|$ derivations.

My question is why then do textbooks assert that we can stop after $2|w|$ derivations instead? Yes, I agree that this is true, but wouldn't it be easier just to stop at $|w|+1$ and above? What am I missing for this condition?

Comment: Which textbooks?

Comment: "An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata", Peter Linz

Answer (score 2):

You increase the length of the *sequential* form with each derivation, but you also need to convert non-terminals to terminals.

Think of a grammar in Chomsky normal form. For each word symbol, you need to create a non-terminal first (and you create *only* one per derivation!) and then convert it into a terminal. That's $2|w| \pm 1$ derivations right there.

Yes, CNF is a little wasteful this way, but finding short derivations isn't its purpose, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Each derivation step replaces applies a production to one non-terminal.
After $|w|-1$ derivation steps you have a sentential form of length $|w|$.
You need one derivation to replace each non-terminal with its corresponding terminal. So the total number of steps is $2|w|-1$.

Comment: Nice answer. It could be misleading though, since it might be false that "after $|w|-1$ derivation you have $|w|$ length sententia form". For example, $S\Rightarrow AS\Rightarrow aS\Rightarrow aBS\Rightarrow abS\Rightarrow abc$. After 3-1 =2 derivations, the sentential form $aS$ is of length 2. Of course, I know what you meant. I am just nitpicking as what you have written might not be your true idea. You would like to hold yourself to a higher standard when your answer could be viewed by many others for years to come.